# Why can't I delete DataSources from my project?

Tags: winforms, entity-framework

So I am starting a new project with an existing database using Windows Forms.  I am trying to use Entity Framework 4 and the steps I do are as follows:
New project->Windows Forms Application (for my front-end app)
Right-Click solution->Add->New Project->Class Library (used for DAL)
Now I want to add the entity model to the DAL and so I right-click on that project and go through the steps of adding the entity model in the wizard.  When it gets done I have the .edmx file, references added and ALSO the DataSources folder with the .datasource file.  I CAN'T remove this.

Why would I need that datasources in the DAL if I am intending to put a object datasource in my front-end??  Seems funny to have 2 projects each having the same datasources.  I am trying to follow the steps in this article and when I load the source from that article for (Seperating data layer from UI Layer) it shows the Data sources only in his app, not the DAL.

Does part of adding a entity data model REQUIRE datasources?  Why can't I delete it and move it to my application project?

I just tested the same steps on my laptop and it works as expected, only the .edmx is created and it doesn't throw in a datasources folder in the properties with a .datasource file.

Comment: It appears that if you choose Data->Show Data Sources VS 2010 automatically adds a datasources folder under the project and you CAN'T delete it until you close the data sources window

Answer (score 1):

It appears that if you choose Data->Show Data Sources VS 2010 automatically adds a datasources folder under the project and you CAN'T delete it until you close the data sources window

I couldn't post it until I waited for 8 hours :-(